# Refreshing an activity every 15 minutes in background and send a notification even if the application is closed

Tags: android, background, background-task

I'm working on an app that take data from a web service and show them in various card view inside a recycler view.
I need to refresh the activity that show the data and send a notification (like "System ok" or "Something went wrong") to the user even if the app is closed every 15 minutes.
I found that Alarm Manager or Work Manager should solve my problem but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Check this for AlarmManager: https://medium.com/@benexus/background-services-in-android-o-862121d96c95, and this for WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper method to do this is to use a JobScheduler. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling). You set it to fetch data from your web service every 15 minutes. Save this data to some persistent cache and have this activity load the data from cache everytime its started